# Assembly language in MIPS Multiply and Divide using MARS

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to figure out why it breaks on the line right after div. maybe I'm setting up div wrong? or storing it wrong? also, did I call it to print the total distance?

```
li $t0, 284  #distance in miles from OR to WA
li $t1, 387  #6 hours and 27 minutes, 6 hours = 360 minutes +27 minutes, 387 minutes
li $t2, 5280 #5280 feet in a mile
li $t3, 60   #60 seconds in a minutes

main:
    mult $t0, $t2        #gets the total feet in the 284 miles and places it into $t4
    mfhi $t4

    mult $t1, $t3       #gets the total seconds in the 6 hours an 27 minutes
    mfhi $t5

    div $t4, $t5    #divides the total feet by the total seconds
    mflo    $t6
        li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t6
    syscall

    addi $v0, $zero, 10 ##system call to leave the program
    syscall         ##exits the program
```

Comment: If you don't want others to see your questions, don't ask them in the first place. Don't delete or truncate questions without necessity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see you loading any system call number into `$v0` before the first `syscall`.

Comment: Am I doing it right? it still doesnt run properly, it compiles but breaks at syscall

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're dividing by 0. How's that possible? Well, your products 284*5280=1499520 and 387*60=23220 fit into 32 bits. `mult` produces 64-bit products, with the most significant 32 bits in the `hi` register and the least significant 32 bits in the `lo` register. So, `hi` is 0 after both `mults`. And yet for some reason you decide to use `hi` and not `lo`.

Also, it is strange that `main:` comes after those `lis`. Those `lis` might not be executing at all because of that.